# promisifyAll in bluebird.js

Tags: javascript, object, promise, bluebird

I am trying to understand how promisifyAll works. i am trying hard to understand the example given in their documentation. Can anyone please give me a simple example, how it works? I am trying to understand the concept and how we can use it. Thank you

```
var objects = {}; 

objects.first = function(){
  console.log("First one is executed");
}

objects.second = function(){
    console.log("second one is executed");

}

objects.third = function(){
    console.log("third one is executed");
}
```

how can we promisify the objects variable? or something like that.

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation?

Comment: You don't have any **callback** on your object functions, so it make no sense to promisify. Promisify is use when you have a callback style and you want to work with it as a promise. Better say what you want to achieve to provide a better advice.

Comment: If there is nothing asynchronous in your code, you cannot promisify it.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand how a `nodeFunction` works. It takes a callback function as the last argument. This callback takes two arguments, the first one is `error` and the second the data. Consider for example `require("fs").readFile`:

```
// This is the callback
function callback (error, data) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('There was an error', error)
  } else {
    console.log('This is the data', data)
  }
}
require('fs').readFile('my-file.txt', callback)
```

Note that this is a convention, there's nothing in JS itself that enforces it.

Let's move to `Promise.promisify` now. This method takes a `nodeFunction` and returns a *promisified* version of it. This is more or less what it does:

```
function promisifiedReadFile (filePath) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    require('fs').readFile(path, function (error, data) {
      if (error) { reject(error) } else { fulfill(data) }
    })
  })
}
```

It's a bit verbose but as you can see you now have a version of `readFile` that returns a promise instead of accepting a callback. Of course, this example is hard-coded for `readFile`, `Promise.promisify` works for any `nodeFunction` instead:

```
const promisifiedReadFile = Promise.promisify(require('fs').readFile)
```

The two `promisifiedReadFile` methods work in the same way.

Last, `Promise.promisifyAll` takes an object, goes through it and finds all the methods, it then applies `Promise.promisify` to each of them.

So, if you call `Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))` you get back a version of the `fs` module where all the methods return promises instead of accepting callbacks.

---

About your example I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but the methods you defined are not `nodeFunctions` so they can't be promisified.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will look into this

Comment: Worth noting that `promisifyAll` *mutates* the object you pass to it. Also, it will add methods with the `Async` suffix, `fs.readFile()` becomes `fs.readFileAsync()`, although the original `fs.readFile()` will still be available under the same name.